# What encoding is this character? And how to handle it in xml

Tags: xml, utf-8, character-encoding

```xml
<tac id="10" name="KD&#11;#36">
```

I have a program that saves in xml (using Java). But after saving this line, the xml cannot be loaded anymore (SAX Parser).
Do I need to change the xml header to something else than UTF-8, if yes, to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric character reference `&#11;`is [illegal in XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets), but it is [allowed in XML 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets). Java's SAX parser should be able to parse XML 1.1, but this requires that the XML declaration at the top of the document specifies version 1.1:

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.

Its "KD" plus the ASCII control character VTAB plus "#36".

Apparently Java cannot properly write that char to xml, so I just use regex to replace it with something else before writing to xml.

Comment: U+000B is legal in XML 1.1 as @nwellnhof pointed out. At the same time, it's extremely unlikely to actually show up in text intentionally, so removing it is *probably* sane (unless you need to perfectly replicate some input).